# how to use ssh-key in vagrant with passphrase?

Tags: linux, ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys, vagrantfile

i have created my custom box for libvirt and generate ssh-key pair for vagrant without pass-phrase . i am  giving private key  in vagrant file like

```
config.ssh.username = "username"
config.ssh.private_key_path = "/path_to_key/id_rsa"
```

after running `vagrant up VM --provider=libvirt` it is working fine without any problem.
Next time i again create new Box and ssh-key with pass-phrase and i am running command `vagrant up with_pass --provider=libvirt` but it not working and not asking for pass-phrase. it stop at

```
==> with_pass:  -- Video Type:        cirrus
==> with_pass:  -- Video VRAM:        9216
==> with_pass:  -- Keymap:            en-us
==> with_pass:  -- Command line : 
==> with_pass: Creating shared folders metadata...
==> with_pass: Starting domain.
==> with_pass: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
==> with_pass: Waiting for SSH to become available..
```

i know it need pass-phrase  but i don't know How to give pass-phrase.

Answer (score -1):

As stated here: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html

you can use `config.ssh.password`.

Comment: thanks for try !! i don't want to use password . i want to use passphrase that i have used while creating ssh key.

Comment: Right. My bad :) Did you try adding the key to ssh agent (```ssh-add```) ?